# Enable debugging in opam packages

Tags: ocaml, opam

For a school project, I'm using Jane Street's Core and Async libraries. I'm trying to debug a problem with a `bind` Unix syscall, so I run `ocamldebug myprogram`. This stops when the exception is raised (`Unix.Unix_error`), but upon backstepping I get the following message:

```
No source file for Async_parallel.Master_process.
```

which is the file in which the error is raised. Is it possible to specify to opam to build the packages I install with debugging information, so that I can use ocamldebug to examine them? Otherwise, what else can I do to get around this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Since 4.01 ocaml compilers will use the `OCAMLPARAM` environment variable to enable certain options. Try running with `OCAMLPARAM="_,g" opam install ...`. Also see https://github.com/ocaml/opam/issues/681

On the other hand debugging this kind of problems is much easier and effective with `strace -e bind -f -ttT ./myprogram`. Also `Unix_error` carries the reason of the error, don't disregard it.

Comment: I can't find any documentation on the `OCAMLPARAM` variable. Do you have any links?

Comment: I guess it is still experimental, use at your own risk - https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/4.02.2/driver/compenv.ml#L144